# in/contains statement lists in lists in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

There are many ways to check if a value is in an array in Javascript. One could extend the Array prototype or one could make use of the in statement.

```
Array.prototype.contains = function(obj) {
    var i = this.length;
    while (i--) {
        if (this[i] === obj) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

> [1,2,3].contains(2)
true
> 3 in [1,2,3]
true
```

Why does this not work for lists in lists?

```
> [[1],[2],[3]].contains([2])
false 
> [3] in [1,2,[3]]
false
```

Surely there should be a simple function for what I am trying to do here?

Comment: You need a deep comparison: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[2]` and `[2]` are two *different* objects that happen to have the same value.